# Predicting from individual and group data

Tags: predictive-models, multilevel-analysis

Suppose that I have a classroom of students who each have taken two tests (A and B). I have the scores for test A and only know the average score for test B. Since students tend to perform similarly on both tests, I want to predict their scores for test B.

In practice I would not expect this to be incredibly accurate -- but am interested in trying to find out if student 1 is generally a 'B' student and the class overall does better/worse on a test, what kind of score should we expect of student 1 on this test.

Comment: Knowing only the average score for test B, you will have to make strong assumptions in order to get anywhere. At a minimum, you will need to assume things about the *distribution* of scores in test B, such as their variance, as well as the range of possible scores on test B. You mention that "students tend to perform similarly," which suggests you have access to additional information about the relationships among the scores. Any such information that you could provide in this question will help people formulate better answers.

Comment: Not knowing the variance is certainly a big problem. For now I am assuming the distribution of scores is on the same scale but centered differently.